# Entity Framework Core 2.0: Error when enumerating over query with group

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following method which simply iterates over orders grouped by client ID.

```
static void LinqWithInto()
{

    using (var db = new EFContext())
    {
        var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Client);
        orders.Load();

        var query = from order in orders
                    group order by order.ClientId into g
                    select new { ClientId = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Orders = g };

        foreach (var group in query)
        {
            WriteLine($"Client Id: {group.ClientId}, Number of orders: {group.Count}");
            foreach (var order in group.Orders)
                WriteLine($"\tOrder Id: {order.OrderId}, Client Id: {order.Client.ClientId}, Client Name: " +
                    $"{order.Client.Name} Payment: {order.Payment}");
        }

    }
}
```

The query fetches orders with associated clients:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public double Payment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

[Table("Client")]
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The code works well in EF6, but in EF Core I get the following error (the variable *query* in *foreach* loop is highlighted):

**System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType' of method 'Void StartTracking(System.Object, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType)''**

I wonder what's wrong here?

Comment: Well, EFC is still in development and query translation is unstable and far from perfect. You've just hit one of the (many) bugs. From the other side, the sample query does not make too much sense :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, this is purely test example. First, I thought this was something about LINQ, and then I decided to replicate it to EF6. And - voila - no error :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in EF Core 2.0 which got addressed in this issue (Contains workaround):
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9551

You can get the testfeed 2.0.3 here (Contains fix):
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/274

Comment: You are welcome, the workaround described in the Issue also solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a repro (which you should post over at [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore)), and a workaround.  As Ivan said, that code doesn't make much sense, as the grouping query will still be sent to the database.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace efCoreTest
{
    [Table("Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public double Payment { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Client")]
    public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();

    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=efCoreTest;Integrated Security=true");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var client = new Client() { Address = "Address", Name = $"Client{i}" };
                    db.Clients.Add(client);

                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        var order = new Order() { Client = client, Payment = 20 };
                        db.Orders.Add(order);
                    }


                }
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                //works
                var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Client).ToList() ;

                //fails
                //var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Client);
                // orders.Load();

                var query = from order in orders
                            group order by order.ClientId into g
                            select new { ClientId = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Orders = g };

                foreach (var group in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Client Id: {group.ClientId}, Number of orders: {group.Count}");
                    foreach (var order in group.Orders)
                        Console.WriteLine($"\tOrder Id: {order.OrderId}, Client Id: {order.Client.ClientId}, Client Name: " +
                            $"{order.Client.Name} Payment: {order.Payment}");
                }




                Console.WriteLine("Complete");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _as the grouping query will still be sent to the database_
The profiler only sent this query:
`
SELECT [o].[OrderId], [o].[ClientId], [o].[Payment], [o.Client].[ClientId], [o.Client].[Address], [o.Client].[Name]
FROM [Order] AS [o]
INNER JOIN [Client] AS [o.Client] ON [o].[ClientId] = [o.Client].[ClientId]`
Nothing more was sent to database.

Comment: Is that query from EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: @ David Browne It was from EF Core. Thus, grouping is made locally.

Comment: I got your point. I switched to EF6 (which works) and saw **two** queries :)